# Instead of showing value; it is showing like this {pitem.Name} {pitem.Condition} {pitem.price}

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

```
<apex:page controller="StoreFrontController" >
<apex:pageBlock title="Our Products">
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="pitem">
<apex:column headerValue="Product">
<apex:outputText value="{pitem.Name}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Condition">
<apex:outputText value="{pitem.Condition}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Price" style="text-align: right;">
<apex:outputText value="{pitem.price}">
</apex:outputText>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class StoreFrontController {
    list<productDisplay> prd;
    public list<productDisplay> getProducts()
    {
        if(prd == null)
        {
            prd = new list<productDisplay>();
            for(product__C item : [ SELECT Id, Name, quantity__c, condition__c, Price__c, 
                                       stock__c FROM product__c]) 
            {
                prd.add(new productDisplay(item));
            }
        }
        return prd;
    }
    public class productDisplay
    {
        public Product__c p;
        productDisplay(Product__c itemDisplay)
        {
            this.p = itemDisplay;
        }
        public String getname
        {
            get{return p.name;}
        }
        public Decimal getPrice
        {
            get{return p.price__c;}
        }
        public String getCondition
        {
            get{return p.condition__c;}
        }
        public Decimal getStock
        {
            get{return(p.Stock__c);}
        }
        public Decimal getQuantity {get{return(p.Quantity__c);set;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your issue more? It is unclear what/where the problem is. There is no mention of `pitem` in your code.

Comment: You will also need to include your visualforce page.

Comment: Actually instead of getting the value in VF page I am getting like this {pitem.Name} {pitem.Condition} {pitem.price}. Pitem is the variable used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include an exclamation mark (!) when referencing variables in your VisualForce page. You are already doing it for `{!products}` but not for the other variables:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!pitem.Name}"/>
...
<apex:outputText value="{!pitem.Condition}"/>
...
<apex:outputText value="{!pitem.price}">
```

You will also need to change your `productDisplay` class so that the variables don't start with "get" as shown below. Without this change would you have to reference these variables via `{!pitem.getPrice}`

```
public class productDisplay
{
    public Product__c p;
    productDisplay(Product__c itemDisplay) {
        this.p = itemDisplay;
    }
    public String name
    {
        get{return p.name;}
    }
    public Decimal price
    {
        get{return p.price__c;}
    }
    public String condition
    {
        get{return p.condition__c;}
    }
    public Decimal stock
    {
        get{return(p.Stock__c);}
    }
    public Decimal quantity {get{return(p.Quantity__c);set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I am getting a different error: Unknown property 'StoreFrontController.productDisplay.price'

Comment: The above mentioned error is showing'

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use proper VF Merge syntax of {! propertyName }

Additionally, you'll need to ensure that their is either a property, or a get method specified for that variable.

Specifically, you'll need to setup properties like this:

Public Type Name {get; set;} // OR {get; private set;}